# Data import operation stops when triggered by a shortcut but works in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with macro, when running it stops while opening a source file (at first sheet - from second sheet should copy 3 ranges of data). While running it in debug mode it works properly step-by-step.
I'm newbie in VBA and cannot locate the mistake in code. Thank you for help!

I had problem with checking is "Summary" sheet already exists but i solved this problem using function and it works currently.

**UPDATE**: When source file (from which data have to be copied) is open, macro works triggered by a shortcut but it should open file, copy the ranges, paste it to the destination sheet. If source file is chosen from pop-up window triggered by macro, it opens and macro stops without copying and pasting.

```
If Not sheet_exists("Summary") Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add( _
After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = _
"Summary"
End If

    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select an Inbound Report File")

Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
Worksheets("Summary").Activate
SrcWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("A:W").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("A:W")
SrcWbk.Close False

    DestWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("A9:F9", Range("A9:F9").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Current Receipt On Stock").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Summary").Select

    DestWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("G9:H9", Range("G9:H9").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Current Receipt On Stock").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Summary").Select

    DestWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("I9:W9", Range("I9:W9").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Current Receipt On Stock").Select
    Range("P2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Summary").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("Current Receipt On Stock").Range("E2").Select
```

Comment: What variable type is `filename`?

Comment: Variable type is String for filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Instead of shortcut I made a button as trigger and macro works, the problem occurs only while triggered by shortcut.**

Thank you for suggestion about removing all `Select`, but the main problem still occurs.

> When you run it step by step it works, but not when you run normally ?
>   It's weird !

That's right, it's weird. I'm noob in VBA and try to understand the code but It stops while macro open workbook in this part:

```
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a Douglas Inbound Report File")

Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
```

it does not start copying the data from **"Summary"** sheet to the same named sheet in destination workbook (where macro is running):

```
Worksheets("Summary").Activate
SrcWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("A:W").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("Summary").Range("A:W")
SrcWbk.Close False
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run it step by step it works, but not when you run normally ? It's weird !

I recommend you to remove all `Select`, it's source of error ! Because may be when you run step by step you select a sheet "manually" and it's why your code run differently.

Like this :

```
Sheets("Current Receipt On Stock").Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
```